# AngularJS Currency & Number filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I currently have this markup

```
{{10000 | currency}}
```

which displays: $10,000

I have a dropdown which asks the user how he wishes to view the number for example if he's from France he is used to seeing the number represented as $10 000 instead of the US number formatting $10,000

Any ideas how to do this with AngularJS currency filter and locale?

Comment: you will need to change the locale dynamically then.  Have a look at the https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale.  It's pretty easy to use.

Comment: I am using dynamic locale but when I change it to for example French it is changing the number format to 10 000 as well as the currency but in this case I do not wish to change both, just the number format

Comment: Well sorry but that doesn't make too much sense.  you could create your own locales but who wants a french locale with usd symbol?